# Expose a Reverse SSH Tunnel on the Remote server

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, iptables, redhat-enterprise-linux, reverse-tunnel

I set up a Reverse SSH tunnel from my home computer to my work server:

```
ssh -f -N -R 19999:localhost:22 remoteuser@server
```

To connect to my home computer I have to first log in to the server and then from there log in to my home computer:

```
otheruser@othermachine$ ssh remoteuser@server
remoteuser@server$ ssh -p 19999 homeuser@localhost
```

But I want to be able to skip one step and connect directly through port 19999, something like:

```
otheruser@othermachine$ ssh -p 19999 homeuser@server
```

I'm not that familiar with `iptables` and I'm have been reading but it seems so confusing just to open a port. I'm pretty sure that I need to add a rule to `iptables`, but is there anything else that I need to do?

The server is RHEL 6 and my home computer is Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to `iptables`, you also need to use the `-g` option with `ssh` (GatewayPorts) *and* the server's config `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` has to have the `GatewayPorts yes` set.

Comment: SO it will be something like `ssh -g homeuser@server` right?

Comment: `ssh -g -p 19999 homeuser@server`, yes.